# Unknown electronic component. Does anyone recognize it?

Tags: resistors, identification

A teacher gave me this electronic component.

In principle it looks like a resistor, but it has no value code.

I measured voltage, ohms, farads, etc.,  but it does not generate results.

Yes, when I hold it between my fingers it seems to give a high amount of resistance, but I don't know if it is because of my physical resistance or if it is with the heat I have a change.

[image: photo of component]

Comment: And what part of your studies is your teacher hoping that giving you an unknown component will help you with. In other words, what is the teachers aim in doing this?

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "does not generate results" - for example zero ohms or infinite resistance.

Comment: @Andyaka my guess would be the teacher doesn't know what it is either but found it in a lab junkbox where it sat since the 1970's.  Question would be if it is an inductor or resistor or atypical obsolete form of capacitor...

Comment: If you measure resistance, you will get **something.** Open circuit?  Short curcuit?  Something in between?  You can't get "nothing" from a resistance reading.

Comment: Is it ceramic? Also, could you please explain the phrase "I hold it between my fingers it seems to give a high amount of resistance"?

Comment: Don't forget to consider that it could be a component with polarity, like a diode, so you should measure resistance in both directions.

Answer (score 3):

Seems I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'll try to post my answer.

To me it seems like an old resistor and it does have a color code, it's black-navy-brown. Or just navy-brown on a black body or the other way around.

I've seen similar resistors in old radio receivers.

Comment: Agreed, it's just a vintage 50s-60s style resistor. I'm guessing that if the OP  "can't get results" he's probably observing varying high resistances (few 100k ohms) he's just measuring the resistance in his fingers and the resistor is a much higher value. Maybe.